# form inside bootstrap modal not formatted

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build a small form inside a bootstrap modal but it is not displaying the fields properly. Please see the image below (it is what is displaying) 
[image]

My code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="updateToFullVersionModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss  ="modal" class="close" type="button">X</button>
            <h4 id="myModalLabel1" class="modal-title"><strong>Upgrade to Full Version</strong></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body mx-3">
                <div class='form-row'>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                        <label class='control-label'>Name on Card</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="CustomerNameCard" type='text' placeholder="Name on Card" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                        <label class='control-label'>Card Number</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="CustomerCreditCardNumber" placeholder="Credit Card Number" size="20" type='text' >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
                        <label class='control-label'>Zip Code</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="CustomerCreditCardZip" placeholder="Postal Code" size="6" type='text' >
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='form-row'>
                      <div class='col-xs-4 form-group cvc required'>
                        <label class='control-label'>CVC</label>
                        <input id="CustomerCreditCardCVV" class='form-control' placeholder='ex. 311' size='4' type='text' >
                      </div>
                      <div class='col-xs-4 form-group expiration required'>
                        <label class='control-label'>Expiration</label>
                        <input class='form-control' id="CustomerCreditCardExpirationMonth" placeholder='MM' size='2' type='text' >
                      </div>
                      <div class='col-xs-4 form-group expiration required'>
                        <label class='control-label'>&nbsp;</label>
                        <input class='form-control' id="CustomerCreditCardExpirationYear" placeholder='YY' size='2' type='text' >
                      </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Close</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"  onClick="updateToFullVersion();">Confirm</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Idk why I have a line under "Name on Card" and the "modal-footer" is not working. Does anyone know why it is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're not balancing your tags. Try closing the input for a start.

Do it like this:

```
<input class='form-control' id="CustomerCreditCardExpirationYear" placeholder='YY' size='2' type='text' />
```

Attention on the closing with "`/>`"

Comment: I closed the inputs, but still the same issue

Comment: It surely looks like an unbalanced html (the line above the first field appears to be a mix up with the header itself). Let me check that again.

Comment: I agree, but I can't find what is causing the problem

Comment: Check for a `<div>` without closing tag too (may be the outtermost one).

Comment: I found the issue. I have to replace <div class='form-row'> to <div class='row'>. I am not sure why

Comment: Can't you inspect the page with the browser, clicking on that line to see from who it belong's?